# Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream while installing tomcat 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

Hi i am trying to install tomcat 7 in eclipse 4.2(juno).

I am going to windows>preferences>servers>add and download and install.

The problem is that the installation starts but after some time it stops and gives the following error.

Error occurred installing server: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i found the solution.

I just installed apache from outside tomcat and at the end of the installation didnot check the box which said run tomcat server but instead i opened eclipse and ran the tomcat server from eclipse.

Thanks all.